# Number of ways to distribute the awards?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Q: There are 25 participant in a contest in which first, second, and third place
prizes are awarded as well as 3 honorable mentions. How many ways are
there to hand out the top three prizes? After those have been selected, from
the remaining participants, how many choices are there for the honorable
mentions (no distinction/ranking is made of these)? How many ways total
are there to give out all the awards?

This is how approached the problem: 
For the first part $$x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = 25; x_{i} > 0$$ 
From that you get $$\binom{24}{2}$$
For the second one I did it in the same way. Since the top three prizes has already been given the number of participant will be 22 $$x_{4} + x_{5} + x_{6} = 22; x_{i} > 0$$ 
 $$\binom{21}{2}$$
As for the last one $$x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} + x_{5} + x_{6} = 25; x_{i} > 0$$ and solving this will give you
 $$\binom{24}{5}$$
Did I approach the problem correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In distributing the first, second, and third place prizes, you did not take into account that three distinct prizes are being distributed to distinct people.  In distributing the honorable mention prizes, what matters is that three of the eligible people are receiving the awards.

Assuming no student receives more than one prize, there are $25$ ways of distributing the first place prize, $24$ ways of distributing the second place prize, and $23$ ways of distributing the third place prize.  Hence, these three distinct prizes can be distributed in $25 \cdot 24 \cdot 23$ ways.

This leaves $22$ students to whom the three honorable prizes may be awarded.  Assuming no student receives more than one prize, there are 
$$\binom{22}{3}$$
ways to select three of the $22$ students to receive an honorable mention prize.

Thus, the number of ways to distribute all of the awards is 
$$25 \cdot 24 \cdot 23 \cdot \binom{22}{3}$$